# How to refer to a static method in Thymeleaf html in java?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I need to use the getMoneyIntoWords() method in the invoice html. But I am getting errors. Refer the code and errors below

// Added below method in MoneyUtil.java

```
 public String getMoneyIntoWords(String input) {

        MoneyConverters converter = MoneyConverters.ENGLISH_BANKING_MONEY_VALUE;

        String str = converter.asWords(new BigDecimal(input));

        return StringUtils.capitalize(str.split("£")[0]);

    }   

<td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
         <span th:text="${MoneyUtil.getMoneyIntoWords(invoice.totalAmountAfterTax)} +'only'" />
       </td>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method moneyIntoWords(java.lang.Integer) on null context object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need special syntax to call a static method in Thymeleaf:

```
<span th:text="${T(com.company.app.money.MoneyUtil).getMoneyIntoWords(invoice.totalAmountAfterTax)} +'only'" />
```

You will need to use the full qualified name of the `MoneyUtil` class.